# Lisp unroll/partial eval function

Tags: debugging, lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way to show the evaluation steps in Common Lisp like follows:

```
> (defun fac (n) (if (= n 0) 0 (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (fac (- n 1))))))
FAC
> (step-by-step (fac 3))
0: (FAC 3)
1: (* 3 (FAC 2))
3: (* 3 (* 2 (FAC 1)))
4: (* 3 (* 2 (1)))
5: (* 3 2)
6: 6
Result: 6
```

Looking for a way to visualize recursion and return values in general for a small course. 
I know of `(step fn)` and `(optimize (debug 3)))` unfortunately this does not produce the desired output, or I don't know how to tell it to.

NOTE: non-emacs/slime solution preferred

Comment: It's unclear how your output should be generated and what's the principle behind it.

Comment: Your example looks like Lisp would do term rewriting, but it's not doing that. It uses a recursive evaluation algorithm.

Comment: I am trying to show how the recursive evaluation can be perceived. (step fn) does something close, but I would like to see the whole expression on each step. Like having a debug print of each function call.

Comment: There isn't a 'whole expression' in Lisp. Either you could just trace the calls you are interested in or you would need to write a custom evaluation, where these expressions are constructed somehow (for example using a stack).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Was afraid that might be my only option.

Comment: "Like having a debug print of each function call."  There's the standard TRACE macro.

Answer (score 7):

It's not everything you asked for, and the specific output is implementation dependent, but you may get some good milage out of the standard [**trace**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm).  It won't show the expansion like you showed, but it's definitely a way to meet *some* of your requirements

> [to] visualize recursion and return values in general … to see the whole expression on each step. Like having a debug print of each function call.

Many implementations include additional arguments that can customize how things get traced, what gets printed, etc.  Here's an example of the default behavior with SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (defun fac (n) (if (= n 0) 0 (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (fac (- n 1))))))
FAC
CL-USER> (trace fac)
(FAC)
CL-USER> (fac 3)
  0: (FAC 3)
    1: (FAC 2)
      2: (FAC 1)
      2: FAC returned 1
    1: FAC returned 2
  0: FAC returned 6
;=> 6
```

In CLISP:

```
CL-USER> (fac 3)
1. Trace: (FAC '3)
2. Trace: (FAC '2)
3. Trace: (FAC '1)
3. Trace: FAC ==> 1
2. Trace: FAC ==> 2
1. Trace: FAC ==> 6
;=> 6
```